# Limits involving indeterminate forms

Tags: calculus

I am trying to find $\lim_{x \to \infty} (\ln x)^{1/x}$ and I have gotten it to $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x \ln x}$.

The answer is $1$ and I just can't figure out why.

Comment: you can write your limit as y = .... and then take the ln on both sides. You can then rewrite your limit appropriately for Hospital's Rule. The outcome of that limit is 0 and from lny=0 follows y=1

Comment: Not sure exactly how that result relates to the given problem. I can see if you take the ln on both sides, you get lnx in the numerator and an x in the denom. That limit is zero.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** if $x\gt 1$, then $(\ln x)^{1/x}=\exp\left(\frac{\ln(\ln x)}{x}\right)$

The behaviour of $\frac{\ln(\ln x)}{x}$ for large $x$ can be found in various ways, for example by using L'Hospital's Rule. Then use the cotinuity of the function $\exp(t)$.